# How to get device unlock count in iphone/ipad even if the application is in background

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am new to iOS can anyone tell me how to detect the device unlock count, from the application even if the application goes to background or if the user kills the application..

Its working in android even if the user kills the application..

can anyone please tell me how to do that...

Comment: You may use `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` in App delegate, & initiate a counter in `NSUserDefaults`  else in shared instance (Singleton class)

Comment: hi i want to count how many times the device is getting locked and unlocked from my application...( even if the application goes background or terminated)..

Comment: If you want to enable your app to work in background mode, then first thing you have to do is go to Capabilities in Target and enable Background modes and take user permission whether he will allow to run app is background or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook into the com.apple.springboard.lockstate event:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application  
         didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

   int notify_token;

   notify_register_dispatch("com.apple.springboard.lockstate",    &notify_token,dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(int token) {
      uint64_t state = UINT64_MAX;
      notify_get_state(token, &state);

      if (state == 0) {
         locked++;
      } else {
         unlocked++;
      }
  });
```

Put this code in your app-delegate